# How to capture start and end time of each sampler into variable, ans pass it as input to sampler request?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

My requirement is, for each Jmeter Http sampler I need pass the current sampler start time and previous sampler end time along with the input Http parameters. Please share me the example to achieve this using "preprocessors" and variabbles.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- `current sampler start time` - you cannot get it in a PreProcessor because Sampler hasn't yet been started, consider getting the current timestamp using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) instead directly in the HTTP Request sampler body. If you still want to do this in Groovy - use [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) like:

  ```
  vars.put('currentTime', System.currentTimeMillis() as String)
  ```
- `previous sampler end time` - can be obtained using `prev` shorthand to [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance

  ```
  vars.put('previousSamplerEndTime', prev.getEndTime() as String)
  ```

In the HTTP Request sampler you can refer the values using `${currentTime}` and `${previousSamplerEndTime}` JMeter Variables references correspondingly

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T,
Hope this should help us in our requirement. I initially used the __time() function which is working